# Using Typscript DT in nextjs 13, imports are not working

Tags: typescript, dictionary, next.js, import

Having a nextjs13 project with Typescript using the `app` folder structure, I try to define my custom types under root/types directory as `d.ts` files.

like

```
declare module "*.svg" {
  import React = require("react");
  export const ReactComponent: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}

declare module "*.png" {
  const value: string;
  export default value;
}

declare module '*.module.css' {
  const styles: { [className: string]: string };
  export default styles;
}

export const CurrencyLocale: Record<string, string> = {
  de: "EUR",
  en: "EUR",
};

export const LocaleMapping: Record<string, string> = {
  de: "de-DE",
  en: "en-EN",
};
```

and when I try to import like: `import { CurrencyLocale, LocaleMapping } from "@/types/global";`

I get: `Module not found: Can't resolve '@/types/global'`

if I rename the file to `global.d.ts`then the import works

If I import as `import { CurrencyLocale, LocaleMapping } from "@/types/global.d";` then works again, but should not be accessible without the `.d` suffix?

Here is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "types": ["jest"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "typeRoots": ["./types"],
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*", "./types/*"],
      "@/types/*": ["./types/*", "./app/types/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts",
    "dictionaries.ts",
    "app/**/*",
    "lib/**/*",
    "tests/**/*",
    "utils/**/*",
    "types/**/*.d.ts",
    "app/**/*.ts",
    "app/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

What I'm missing in this case?

Comment: There's a lot wrong here. For 1 one, that isn't a valid `.d.ts` file because it contains implementations. 2, those asset modules declarations, ie `"*.png"`, will be pursed as module augmentations because they're inside a file containing export statements, which is to say a module. Place your ambient module declarations in a different file.

Comment: @AluanHaddad thanks for Feedback, can you give me some examples based on remarks?